# Filter difference between two objects JS

Tags: javascript, json, object, filtering

I try to find the most effective way to compare two arrays of objects and return filtered difference in JavaScript.

I build an app to update stock in DB. But this app can use many users in the same time. I would like to avoid calling API and refresh all data in app each time changes are made, bcz database is too big and loading time is long. I have and old data locally, with help of MQTT I receive new data the moment its updated by someone. The goal is to find the difference between two objects and update locally only the one that has changes. Objects looks like this:

```
 let oldData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 15 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 3, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]
let newData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 20 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 3, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]
```

The only way I can think about it's foreach. But in real life each of arrays will contain thousands of objects, so I would like to avoid iterations type of: (my working func)

```
 let oldData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]
 let newData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
 ]

 const filterObjDiff = () => {
   var obj1 = oldData as StockUpdate.stockMqttResponse[]
   var obj2 = newData as StockUpdate.stockMqttResponse[]
   obj1.forEach(oldD => {
     obj2.forEach(newD => {
        if (
         oldD.affiliateid == newD.affiliateid &&
         oldD.artnr == newD.artnr &&
         oldD.stock != newD.stock
       ) {
        console.log('diff', newD)
       }
     })
   })
 }
```

Is there an effective way to white func

```
  const FilterObjectDiff = (oldData, newData) => {
   
  // filter here without iterations

    return [ 
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 20 }
     ]
   }
```

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Your data is always unsorted? Like affiliateid is never sorted?

Comment: If each entry had a unique id you can just update that one object directly.

Comment: As I understand it they have a unique (although composite) ID. The combination of `artnr` and `affiliateid` is unique.

Comment: yes, its always unsorted. And local data has more params, it looks different. But the key is unique affiliateId and artnr id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from `oldData` using a combination of `affiliateid` and `artnr` as the key, and then iterate `newData` in your `FilterObjectDiff` function, checking

1. If the new `affiliateid`/`artnr` combination exists in `oldData`; and
2. If it does, if the stock level is the same

If neither of these cases are true, then the `newData` needs to update the DB.

We use a `Map` as lookup time is `O(1)` and thus the lookup time for all of `newData` is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of `newData`.

```js
let oldData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 15 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 3, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]
let newData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 20 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 3, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 1, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]

let oldMap = new Map(oldData.map(o => [`${o.artnr}-${o.affiliateid}`, o.stock ]))

var s

const FilterObjectDiff = (newData) => newData
  .filter(o => (s = oldMap.get(`${o.artnr}-${o.affiliateid}`)) ?
          s != o.stock :
          true)
          
console.log(FilterObjectDiff(newData))
```

Comment: Thank you vary much! Nice idea with mapping. Just needed to add types for typescript:  newData: Array<{ artnr: number; affiliateid: number; stock: number }> and initiate 'var s' before s = oldMap.get...

Comment: @Natalia no worries - I'm glad I could help. Apologies for the lack of variable declarations; it was late. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to improve the performance is with Hash Map since it's O(1) of finding the specific value with a key. I've refactored it with Hash Map and it's equivalent.

```js
    let oldData = [
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
      { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
    ]
    let newData = [
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
      { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
      { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
    ]
    
    const createMap = (data) => {
      const map = new Map();
      data.forEach(stock => {
        map.set(`${stock.artnr}:${stock.affiliateid}`, stock);
      });
      return map;
    };
    
    const filterObjDiff = () => {
      var oldMap = createMap(oldData);
      var newMap = createMap(newData);
      const stockKeys = new Array(oldMap.keys());
      stockKeys.forEach(([key, oldStockData]) => {
        const newStockData = newMap.get(key);
        if (
          oldStockData.stock != newStockData.stock
        ) {
         console.log('diff', newStockData)
        }
      });
   }
   
   filterObjDiff();
```

Comment: This code is broken, try switching the first two lines in `oldData`. Now I get `{ artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 }` instead of `{ artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 }`. And there's no way that this code could mention any new items, items in `newData` that have no counterpart in `oldData`.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. By creating a unique ID from `artnr` and `affiliateid`, mapping the old and the new data by that unique id and compare the values in that hashmap

```js
let oldData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 }
]
let newData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 3, stock: 2 }
]

// use an object as a hashmap
const map = {};
const getOrCreateEntry = ({ artnr, affiliateid }) => map[`${artnr}:${affiliateid}`] ??= [null, null];

// fill the hashmap
for (const item of oldData) getOrCreateEntry(item)[0] = item;  // old item
for (const item of newData) getOrCreateEntry(item)[1] = item;  // new item

Object.values(map).forEach((diff) => {
  if(diff[0]?.stock === diff[1]?.stock) return; // these stayed the same
  
  console.log("%o -> %o", ...diff);
});
```

2. by sorting `oldData` and `newData` in a similar way, then using two indices to iterate over both arrays at the same time. Using the same sort function to determine which index is behind the other.

This minimizes the comparisons between the two arrays and doesn't require the memory of a hashmap.

```js
let oldData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 10 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 2, stock: 2 },
]
let newData = [
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 1, stock: 11 },
  { artnr: 12, affiliateid: 2, stock: 1 },
  { artnr: 13, affiliateid: 3, stock: 2 },
]

const order = (a,b) => a.artnr - b.artnr || a.affiliateid - b.affiliateid;

oldData.sort(order);
newData.sort(order);

const diff = (oldItem, newItem) => {
  if (oldItem?.stock === newItem?.stock) return;

  console.log(oldItem, newItem);
}

// two indices one for oldData, one for newData
let i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < oldData.length && j < newData.length) {
  const sort = order(oldData[i], newData[j]);
  
       if (sort < 0) diff(oldData[i++], null);  // i has to catch up to j
  else if (sort > 0) diff(null, newData[j++]);  // j has to catch up to i
  else diff(oldData[i++], newData[j++]);        // same artnr && affiliateid
}
// I'm done with one of the arrays, nothing more to compare. pick up the rest
while (i < oldData.length) diff(oldData[i++], null);
while (j < newData.length) diff(null, newData[j++]);
```